# Get part of JSON response object with Spring RestTemplate

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to consume [this](https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/771310/feeds.json?api_key=56RYCYHCGNMAIC7G&results=2), by following the tutorial from http://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/.

And I am interested in the "feeds" part of the response only.

My question is:

- Is there any other way without using the `toString()` method in the tutorial. As, I want to access the some parts of response body and display it on a webpage.

Please, provide me with the details of the model and controller.

Comment: It is possible to use the string and you get your data with regular expressions.

Comment: add the code in the post